# rspec testing throws Uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Please forgive any shortcomings in this (my first-ever) post on StackOverflow. I'm brand new to Ruby on Rails. I'm following the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). I have spent many unsuccessful hours consulting other threads discussing the same Name Error that I'm raising in this question.

Any attempt of mine to run an rspec test like so: $bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
throws the now infamous error: `': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Let me know if there's any more information I should provide you in order to get the ball rolling.

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'  
ruby '2.0.0'  
    #ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0  

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'  
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'  
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'  
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'  
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'  
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'  

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'  
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'  
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.  
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'  
  # gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'  
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'  
  # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'  
end  

group :test do  
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'  
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'  
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false  
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'  

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.  
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'  

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.  
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'  
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'  
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'  
end  

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'  
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'  
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'  
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'  
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'  
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'  

group :doc do  
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false  
end  

group :production do  
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'  
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'  
end
```

Here is my spec/models/user_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'  

describe User do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

Here is my app/models/user.rb file:
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    end

Here is my spec_helper.rb file:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

require 'test/unit'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

I have definitely run bundle install. I can also confirm that I've already created the database and run the migration (db/test.sqlite3 already exists)

Comment: Please show `spec/models/user_spec.rb` and `app/models/user.rb`  Also please confirm that you have created the database (`rake db:create`) and run migrations (`rake db:migrate`) and done `bundle install`.

Comment: You might also shared your `spec_helper.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks guys, edits added above. Please let me know if there's more I can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `spec_helper.rb`, you have the following line *twice*:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Delete the first instance (the one on line 2). This is what is causing the error. 
Having this line before `require 'rspec/rails'` will cause problems because we don't know what `Rails` is, and so we cannot call the `root` method. 
The second instance (on line 13) is fine because this is after `require 'rspec/rails'`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove redundant `require 'spec_helper'` line from your `spec_helper.rb` file.