# rspec - uninitialized constant Rails (NameError) - a new case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Off course I read this:

[rspec testing throws Uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692297/rspec-testing-throws-uninitialized-constant-rails-nameerror)

But I am sure that there is nothing wrong with my code.

Just because of the operation system! (Thread?)

Here is the error message when ran `rspec`:

```
/home/user/testapp/spec/spec_helper.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core.rb:98:in `configure'
    from /home/user/testapp/spec/spec_helper.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `block in requires='
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `requires='
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `process_options_into'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

The L26 of the spec_helper file is:

```
Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = false
```

Comment: do you added `require 'rspec/rails'` in spec_helper

Comment: Yes, I added. After I ran `bin/rspec`, it works! Do you know why?

Comment: bin/rspec will require and load all the files through spring ....

Comment: Anyway, this method works well. But why the system `rspec` not work, I don't know now.

Comment: `require 'rspec/rails'
    Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = false` add in the above sequence then run

Comment: Then got a new error: `/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:90:in `<class:ERB>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::ENCODING_FLAG (NameError)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146619/discussion-between-cloud-cloud-and-rajarshi-das).