# meaningless rspec uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, autoload

I have a rails app and running on a VPS, the installation steps of Ruby, Rails, and RSpec are identical on my laptop and VPS (followed by the [same instruction](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04)).
But when I want to test the app using RSpec on the VPS it gives the `uninitialized constant` error (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692297/rspec-testing-throws-uninitialized-constant-rails-nameerror)). the exact clone of the project runs perfectly without any errors on my laptop!
Although the tests are executing on my laptop without any problems, I tried the solutions exist on the web but didn't help me -- even I reinstalled Ruby, Rails, and RSpec on the server!

---

I Need to mention that the app runs perfectly on server through the web(the app is a web-site) without any problem. Definitely this is a RSpec issue; not Ruby or Rails.

#### Quesions:

1. What is wrong with RSpec?
2. How can I fix this?

---

#### Edit:

The exact error output is as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    32: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    31: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    30: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    29: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    28: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    26: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    25: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    24: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
    23: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    22: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `process_options_into'
    21: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `each'
    20: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `block in process_options_into'
    19: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `requires='
    18: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `each'
    17: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `block in requires='
    16: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `require'
    15: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/rails_helper.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/rails_helper.rb:17:in `each'
    13: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/rails_helper.rb:19:in `block in <top (required)>'
    12: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/rails_helper.rb:19:in `each'
    11: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/rails_helper.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    10: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     9: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     8: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     7: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     6: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     5: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/support/helpers/api.rb:1:in `<main>'
     4: from /var/www/www.site.com/spec/support/helpers/api.rb:2:in `<module:APIHelper>'
     3: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:42:in `load_missing_constant'
     2: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
     1: from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant APIHelper::AuthHelper (NameError)
```

Summary:

```
`block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant APIHelper::AuthHelper (NameError)
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error logs?

Comment: @KartikeyTanna question edited

Comment: This feels like some kind of constant name resolution issue. Hard to tell more without a [mcve].

Comment: @SergioTulentsev then why is this executing on my laptop without any errors!?

Comment: @dariush: for any number of reasons. App preloader (like spring) comes to mind first. For example, in the preloaded app instance that constant exists and is resolvable. But if you were to boot the app from scratch, you'd hit the error.

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong with `RSpec`?

There is nothing wrong with `RSpec`.

> How can I fix this?

You are not supposed to run your test suite in production. There are many steps made by different tools in the toolset to prevent you from doing that (like an implicit environment variable setting.) If you are still positive you want to run your tests remotely (which you should not,) an explicit environment setting should probably help:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle install
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec
```

Comment: Running test in production is not my objective... I have the exact problem with Gitlab-CI; since problems are identical if I solve it on the server my problems with CI will also be solved! AND also explicit environment setting didn't work!